# .htaccess - Проблема

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте .
Есть правила в начале хитачес

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

не могу понять,  досконально, что они делают, но когда ставлю после

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*)\.сайт\.ru$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/(.*)/)?$ index.php?smgeo=%2 [L]
```

то этот код не хочет работать.

Конкретно : у меня динамические поддомены для городов и т.д. Хочу получать значение гео - положения.

Объясните дилетанту, почему я могу получить значение только тогда, когда ставлю правило раньше текущих  + при заходе на поддомен, в таком случае,  теряются стили .

Спасибо =))

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас там на правилах **L** - значит остановиться и дальше не ходить.

Если вы свой код для поддоменов ставите после тех правил, то до него, скорее всего просто очередь не доходит.